# onError img function is not working/triggered in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, symfony, twig, components

I've written React components to replace the html twig components which are currently being used in a Symfony project that I'm working on. However, not every instance of an Article brings back an image url and this stops the page from loading for these particular articles.

Here's what I've got for the article component:

```js
function ArticleImage({ articleImageUrl, articleImageAlt, articleImageCaption }) {

  const addDefaultSrc = (e) => {
    e.target.src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/Flag_of_.svg";
    e.target.onerror = null;
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.articleImage}>
      <img
        onError={addDefaultSrc}
        src={articleImageUrl}
        alt={articleImageAlt}
      />
      {articleImageCaption}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ArticleImage;
```

Comment: Maybe try to replace   onError={addDefaultSrc} by         onError={(e) => addDefaultSrc(e)}

Answer (score 0):

Don't update DOM directly. Just change state.

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [{url, alt}, setImage] = useState({
    url: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/-1/100/100.jpg',
    alt: 'test'
  })
  
  const onError = () => {
    setImage(image => ({
      ...image,
      url: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/194/100/100.jpg'
    }))
  }

  return <div>
    <img src={url} onError={onError} alt={alt}/>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```